# what should the size of a flash game in Facebook be

Tags: game-design, flash, server, facebook

I'm developing a flash game and i want to put it in Facebook 
,My question is the Proper maximum  size for it.
500 KB
1 MB ??

Comment: nitpick: MB, not MG

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm taking you to mean .swf size, for loading vs presentation?

I found [this link finding the average sizes for flash files.](http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2010/07/23/the-perfect-swf-file-size-of-your-flash-games/)
Most seem to be 1MB-5MB. As long as you have a decent loading screen that keeps people attracted, and it's not too much of a wait, then it'll be fine.

On Facebook, everyone's bored. :P